# Delphi XE2: Use msbuild to build a project in command line prompt error MSB4067

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe2

I have a project that build fine with Delphi XE2 IDE.

I try to build the project using msbuild in command line console:

```
SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild /p:config=Debug /target:Build /verbosity:diag myproj.dproj
```

MSBuild prompt the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(674,9): error MSB4067: The element <__ShouldBuildVersion> beneath element <PropertyGroup> is unrecognized.
```

I compared both msbuild output from IDE and command line and found that the IDE msbuild output has extra output line:  Building with tools version "2.0".

Perhaps there are some parameters I didn't setup properly in command line usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi XE2 use MsBuild from .NET Framework v3.5

See rsvars.bat in bin directory.

Comment: To elaborate, don't set up the build environment youself, simply call rsvars.bat

Comment: I think the I only need to set environment variable BDS and using .NET 3.5.  Invoke rsvars.bat is not really necessary.